# Powerautomate get columnnames dynamically in an excel file uploaded on sharepoint

Tags: excel, sharepoint, power-automate

For powerautomate I am trying to get the column names dynamically in order to insert their values into columns of another excel file. For example, the values of column C of the file created should always be inserted into column D of the other file already present on Sharepoint
I know it is possible to get the table name of the excel file and to list the rows and insert them into another Excel file by using 'Apply to each'. Basically, when I am creating my flow I still need to assign the proper column values which are not listed since the file does not exist a priori in the folder. But I am not sure if it is possible to list the unknown columns and assign them by number in order to insert them  correspondingly into another Excel file.

Comment: Kinda hard to follow you exactly but I'm sure Office Scripts can help you.  You can run a script over an Excel file really easily.  A bit like a macro but using Typescript in the cloud.  Look it up ...!

Comment: I am trying to use Excel functions. Is it possible to  get Excel scripts dynamically(the content of the uploaded file needs to be inferred by the PA flow)?

Comment: Yes, that’s the simple answer. Just look it up and have a go … Office Scripts.